# Suggestion(s) for deserializing Json objects which has some attributes with a dynamic type with gson

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

I want to deserialize the following object:

```
{
  "qid": "226",
  "parent_qid": "225",
  "sid": "298255",
  "gid": "25",
  "type": "M",
  "title": "SQ001",
  "question": "question text",
  "preg": null,
  "help": null,
  "other": "N",
  "mandatory": null,
  "question_order": "1",
  "language": "de",
  "scale_id": "0",
  "same_default": "0",
  "relevance": "1",
  "modulename": "",
  "available_answers": "No available answers",
  "subquestions": "No available answers",
  "attributes": "No available attributes",
  "attributes_lang": "No available attributes",
  "answeroptions": "No available answer options",
  "defaultvalue": null
}
```

Members with types:

```
private HashMap<String, String> available_answers;

private HashMap<Integer, SubQuestion> subquestions;
```

My problem is that in some cases the attributes "answeroptions" and "available_answers" ( perhaps one or two more) aren't just strings but other objects.

A) I read about creating a custom deserializer to handle such cases but this would lead to the case that I also would have to deserialize the other attributes with static types ( more unnecessary code ).

B) Another approach which came to my mind is that I could "deserialize" the attributes to JsonObjects and deserialize them completely in the corresponding getters.

So my question is if you could suggest me approach a), b) or another one.

Greetings and thanks in advance!

Comment: For (a) you don't need to write deserialize for the entire object you can deserialize field wise. And I think (a) is better then. And it's opinion based question accually

Comment: Do you have control over the JSON structure? Having a field whose value is a different type depending on context seems like a code smell in my opinion.

Comment: No, the JSON structure comes from an API.

Comment: @Eklavya Thanks for the answer. Could you please give me another hint? I only found infos about custom deserialization with a custom deserializer or typeadapter for own classes and default classes not for generic collections like I use. I think the best would be to set for example available_answers to null if the JSON field is a String.

Answer (score 0):

If these fields only have a string JSON value if they have *no value*, then you could use the [`@JsonAdapter` annotation](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html) and a custom [TypeAdapterFactory](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html):

```java
/**
 * Only for use on fields annotated with {@code @JsonAdapter}.
 */
public class StringAsNullTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getAdapter(type);
        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
            @Override
            public void write(JsonWriter out, Object value) throws IOException {
                // You will have to implement this in case you are
                // also writing JSON data
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
            
            @Override
            public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                if (in.peek() == JsonToken.STRING) {
                    in.skipValue(); // skip the string
                    return null;
                }
                return delegate.read(in);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

You can then use that TypeAdapterFactory like this:

```java
class Quiz {
    public String qid;
    public String parent_qid;
    
    // ...
    
    @JsonAdapter(StringAsNullTypeAdapterFactory.class)
    public HashMap<String, String> available_answers;
    @JsonAdapter(StringAsNullTypeAdapterFactory.class)
    public HashMap<Integer, SubQuestion> subquestions;
}
```

You then use your Gson instance as usual, there is no further configuration required.